# How to convert time from UTC to PST in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, timezone, utc, pst

I Ruby on rails application, i am getting time in UTC from database (i.e. in active record object). I want to convert the time to PST before displaying to UI.
I tried doing this
    dataFromDB = DataTable.find_by_sql("select time from datatables");
    dataFromDB[0].time = dataFromDB[0].time.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")

But its not working, it displays the same time i.e. in UTC.

Comment: Can't you just keep the Time information in UTC and only use the in_time_zone method in your view, when you are displaying it?

Answer (score 5):

You can use in_time_zone method for that. Something similiar to below

```
Time.parse("2014-09-12 04:49").in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)')
```

Comment: PST vs PDT you can get either under various circumstances.

Comment: @ajbraus: I did not understand what are you trying to say.

Comment: @Saurabh -- that means depending whether daylight savings time has occurred you will get either PDT or PST. If you call this method March 8 - November 1 you will get PDT; if you call this method November 2 - March 7 you will get PST.

Comment: But isn't it right then? While in daylight saving, PDT is the more relevant time. I am not sure why @ajbraus down voted the answer.