# Rails: Converting created_at to PST

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to convert the `created_at` to this format January 12, 2:00 PM PST.

The first step I tried was to convert the `created_at` field to Pacific Standard Time (PST).

However, I'm stuck - I can't even get past this step.

I've tried these, but neither worked:

```
Time.parse(self.created_at).in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)')

time = Time.parse(self.created_at)
time.in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)')
```

I receive `no implicit conversion of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone into String` when I do this.

I based it on these questions:

[How do you convert the following time from UTC to EST in Ruby (without Rails)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49561529/how-do-you-convert-the-following-time-from-utc-to-est-in-ruby-without-rails)

[How to convert time from UTC to PST in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073482/how-to-convert-time-from-utc-to-pst-in-rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is already a datetime, you should be able to just do this to convert it:

```
self.created_at.in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)')
```

Don't forget to save the new time zone to the record in the database.
Time.parse() is meant to convert strings into datetime(https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Time/parse/class).